# Batch File Using Net User "Username Not Found" Batch Hangs No Prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dns, errorlevel

My batch script does the following:

1. user types in username and is added to a variable
2. trick to ask for password (hides input from user) and adds to variable
3. checks username and password authentication for domain GROUP using "net user" command
4. If user is found in set group, continue to map drive.
5. If user is not part of group restart at beginning

This script works when the username is found.
This script works when a username is found in a group

The problem is if the username is NOT FOUND.
When the user is NOT FOUND, it reports the "More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2221."

It just sits there and does not continue to prompt or anything.
I echoed the errorlevel and it comes out to 0, and reports the 0.  However it still just sits there never reaching command prompt or going where the GOTO tells it.

I have put in errorlevels and I am unsure why it is stuck after the error message and does not continue.  It is as if the batch script is not releasing from somewhere.

```
@echo off
:Question
Echo.
Echo.
SET /P HelperName=Enter Witness' Name:
Echo.
If %HelperName% EQU %Username% GOTO SameUserName

cls
echo hP1X500P[PZBBBfh#b##fXf-V@`$fPf]f3/f1/5++u5>%temp%\ftp.com
set /p password=What is your password? <nul
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('%temp%\ftp.com') do set "password=%%i"
del %temp%\ftp.com


cls
set i=0
set group=WGD
set user=%HelperName%
echo Checking if %user% is member of %group%...
for /f %%f in ('"net user %user% /domain | findstr /i %group%"') do set    /a i=%i%+1
if %i% gtr 0 (goto :member)

:nomember
echo %user% is not member of %group% Please Try Again
goto :question


:member
net use L: \\10.10.10.10\foldernamehere\TEMP /user:wgd\%helpername% %password%
if [%errorlevel%]==[0] goto deletedrive
goto error

:deletedrive
net use /delete L:
goto start
```

It is as if the script in still in another function.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems like I was not waiting long enough for the message to finish.  It hangs for a bit, then continues on through the script.  The wait however for the help message to clear is a little long, if you know how to clear faster please let me know.